# Как в C# с помощью цикла Foreach вывести массив в обратном порядке

Tags: c#, массивы, foreach

Как в C# с помощью цикла Foreach вывести массив в обратном порядке  ? и возможно ли это. буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: о каком цикле `Foreach` идет речь?

Comment: о обычном , Я только учу язык и не знаю что их несколько ну вот допустим код вывода массива foreach (int i in data) {
  
    Console.Write(i );
    
} 
Console.WriteLine(); как мне  вывести массив в обратном порядке?

Comment: `foreach(var i in data.Reverse()){}`

Comment: понял, спасибо!

Comment: Это учебное задание? А какие-нибудь дополнительные условия есть? Ну, там, без двойного расхода памяти?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-foreach-statement) работает с итератором. У массивов по умолчанию итератор идет с первого элемента к последнему.

Поэтому просто `foreach(var el in array)` всегда будет в прямом порядке.

Для обратного можно взять метод [`Reverse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.reverse?view=net-8.0) который вернет итератор проходящийся с конца

```
foreach(var el in array.Reverse())
```